# How can I get someone to use PGP in emails

Tags: windows, pgp

I do my part and ready to use PGP. There is a another user who is new to PGP.I have windows running, I did some installations to get PGP running.How can I get that user start using PGP ? what happens if I send a PGP encrypted email to that user? does that use have to make all installations I made on windows?

Comment: its good that you're equipping yourself with the tools to make use of your facilities securely, but unless you have a basic understanding of how these work, you are no better off, and potentially worse off. You can't send an encrypted email to that user unless you have their PGP key. They can't provide you with a PGP key if they don't use PGP.

Comment: This is a social relationship question, and unanswerable in general at that. If the other user **really** wants PGP-enabled e-mails, he/she will do what is necessary (including rummaging through the Web and learning arcane settings).

Comment: You also have to understand what PGP is for and what are its shortcomings. It will not render your communications invisible or unbreakable...

Comment: @deerhunter I am open to other solutions as long as they are open source which are as you say unbreakable and invisible.

Comment: No such solutions exist over public e-mail system.

Comment: what are the shortcomings  of PGP ? google says not too much.

Comment: "*I am open to other solutions*" - that's nice. Now all you need to do is define a problem to solve. "*as long as they are open source which are as you say unbreakable and invisible.*" Any open source solution you find that is "unbreakable and invisible" will not be "unbreakable and invisible" simply because it is open source.

Comment: open source tools are allowed to use encryption algorithms.RSA AES etc.

Comment: "Symantec is unique in the commercial software industry in that we make our source code available for cryptographic review "  http://tinyurl.com/jhg5l34

Comment: @RobM why do you think symantec makes source code open? To make it breakable and visible. It is nice you simply solve problems.

Comment: I approve of open source and public auditing of encryption algorithms, I'd be a fool not to, but I can assure you that nothing magically happens to make code more secure just because someone said "I know, let's make it open source". Google "Heartbleed" and think about how long the bugs that made that possible existed in open source code. You're making a huge mistake if you think that open source code is somehow magically "unbreakable". Your misunderstanding is precisely one of the reasons that open source code *isn't* necessarily secure.

Answer (score 3):

If you just **sign** the email, he **can read it** without having the required client software for PGP. **He won't be able to verify the signature** though. He'd also see a weird attachment. (This is possible because **your own key** is used in the signing process)
The attachment is named **signature.asc** and contains the signature data:

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
      ...Signature...
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

If you **encrypt** the email using PGP, the recipient would have to use a software to decrypt the PGP email or else **he wouldn't be able to read it**. (This is not possible because **you need the recipients public key to be able to encrypt the email**, but in case the recipient has a public key but doesn't have access to PGP software the that moment, you can send him the email but he won't be able to open it)

So the recipient would have to use the software required to decrypt messages and be able to respond to your emails in a secure manner(with encryption and signature).

---

**PGP Lacks Usability**

The issue with PGP is that it's not usable for normal computer users at all. There's not good addon for new versions of outlook (or it's not free). Using PGP4Win, you will have to encrypt your email and files in the software and then move them to your email client and upon receipt you will have to copy the email into PGP4Win to be able to decrypt it so nothing happens automatically it's all manual and cumbersome. It's not built into the process and is not ubiquitous so only expert users will be able to use this tool.  Let alone the [Web Of Trust](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/760909-pgp-web-of-trust-core-concepts) which is ignored most of the time.

Regarding to **Web Of Trust** (PGP creator Phil Zimmermann in 1992 in the manual for PGP version 2.0):

> As time goes on, you will accumulate keys from other people that you may want to designate as trusted introducers. Everyone else will each choose their own trusted introducers. And everyone will gradually accumulate and distribute with their key a collection of certifying signatures from other people, with the expectation that anyone receiving it will trust at least one or two of the signatures. This will cause the emergence of a decentralized fault-tolerant web of confidence for all public keys.

---

**Support Status under different Operating Systems**

The support may be better in Mac OSX and Linux but you're still limited to specific clients.

- Under Mac OSX you can use [GPG Tools (EFF Tutorial)](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-use-pgp-mac-os-x) which integrates well with the built in mail application.
- Under Linux there are various tools([EFF Tutorial For Linux](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-use-pgp-linux)) providing GUI and shell interface. (*As a side note: an average linux user is usually expert enough to be able to handle PGP's complexity.)*
- Under windows you can use [Enigmail](https://www.enigmail.net/documentation/gpgsetup.php) or [GPG4win](https://www.deepdotweb.com/2015/02/21/pgp-tutorial-for-windows-kleopatra-gpg4win/) package but the available tools may not integrate very well, if at all with outlook or the default mail app for windows (windows 8 and windows 10 versions), so while this is possible to use PGP under windows it is a bigger learning curve for average windows users. ([EFF Tutorial For Windows](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-use-pgp-windows))

Comment: In that message is there a warning like, click below link to install client software etc? I need to direct that user how to handle this his/herself.

Comment: @hakkican added the info to the answer, there's a file named signature.asc in the attachment which contains the signature but doesn't tell the user what to download or how to validate it. You can add this data about how to use PGP in the bottom of your emails if you're willing to but it's not built-in.

Comment: what do you mean by `The issue with PGP is that it's not usable at all` ? do you mean user friendly or something?

Comment: yes, the term usability in software design has this meaning: "usability is the degree to which a software can be used by specified consumers to achieve quantified objectives with effectiveness, efficiency, and satisfaction in a quantified context of use.". And by that I mean it's not user friendly enough to be embraced by most people.

Comment: I can use PGP on linux.At the moment other user is on windows that is why I am trying it on windows.what do you mean better support? any link to read  would be useful as well.I